# how to center align a div containing floats without fixed width

Tags: html, css

I have a ul menu inside a wrapper div. each li element has float:left (this is a horizontal menu).
I want to center the menu in my page container (around 1100px), but I don't know what the size of the menu will be so I can't use "margin:0 auto".

I tried many different things, but I just can't get this to work.

This is a menu in wordpress, so the markup of ul and wrapper div is generated by wordpress. would prefer not to mess with that...

Comment: use margin:0 auto; but also use display:block; and left:50%; Hope this helps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define your container `display:inline-block` and align the text to the center of the container by setting the property `text-align:center`, like so:

**CSS**

```
.nav > li {
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; /* ie7 fix */
    zoom:1; /* hasLayout ie7 trigger */
}

.nav {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: @Andres llich my nav li css   float: left;  margin: 0 10px; 
if i am use display inline-block instead float left my circle(list-style-type) remove but i want this list style type and ul in center

Answer (score 4):

It's better you can use `display:inline-block` property for this. like this:

```
body{
    text-align:center;
}
.parent{
    text-align:left;
    background:red;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;/* For IE7*/
    *zoom:1;/* For IE7*/
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/pJs6e/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div style="position: relative; width:100%">
    <div style="position: relative; left: 50%; float: left;">
      <div style="position: relative;   right: 50%;">

        <!-- the image width is unknown -->
        <img src="https://react-bootstrap.github.io/assets/logo.png" />
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
```

https://jsbin.com/miteliwafu/edit?html,output